# I am getting an undefined index tmp_name notice

Tags: php

I am trying to insert the name of the file into the "AudioFile" column in the "Audio" Table. Problem is that it keeps giving me an undefined index error: tmp_name line 45. This means when I try to insert the name of a file, instead of doing the below:

Audio

```
AudioId (auto)  AudioFile
1               AudioFiles/cat.png
2               AudioFiles/cat_2.png
3               AudioFiles/cat_3.png
```

It is doing this below:

Audio

```
AudioId (auto)  AudioFile
1               AudioFiles/_2.png
2               AudioFiles/_2.png
3               AudioFiles/_2.png
```

So my question is why can't it find the tmp name and hence inserts incorrect file name in the table:

```
$result = 0;



if( file_exists("AudioFiles/".$_FILES['fileAudio']['name'])) {
    $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileAudio']['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($parts);
    $base = implode(".",$parts);
    $n = 2;

    while( file_exists("AudioFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
    $_FILES['fileAudio']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileAudio"]["tmp_name"],  //line 45 notice appears
    "AudioFiles/" . $_FILES["fileAudio"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileAudio"]["tmp_name"],
      "AudioFiles/" . $_FILES["fileAudio"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;
  }

    $audiosql = "INSERT INTO Audio (AudioFile) 
    VALUES (?)";

        if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($audiosql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }

            //Dont pass data directly to bind_param store it in a variable
$insert->bind_param("s",$aud);

//Assign the variable
$aud = 'AudioFiles/'.$_FILES['fileAudio']['name'];

 $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insert->close();
```

Below is the form:

```
 var $fileAudio = $("<form action='audioupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_audio' onsubmit='return audioClickHandler(this);' class='audiouploadform' >" + 

    "<p class='audiof1_upload_process' align='center'>Loading...<br/><img src='Images/loader.gif' /><br/></p>" +

    "<p class='audiof1_upload_form' align='center'><br/><span class='audiomsg'></span><label>" + 

    "Audio File: <input name='fileAudio' type='file' class='fileAudio' /></label><br/><br/><label class='audiolbl'>" + 

    "<input type='submit' name='submitAudioBtn' class='sbtnaudio' value='Upload' /></label>" + 

    "<iframe class='upload_target_audio' name='upload_target_audio' src='#' style='width:300px;height:300px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention that line 45 is here `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileAudio"]["tmp_name"]` I commented the line in the code

Comment: yeah html form is included, it is within ajquery variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT's quite hard to quess which line is 45, but rule of thumb here is that if it says that index in undefined then it really is. There are two common reasons: you made typo in index name trying to read it, or it simply is not there. You can easily check what indexes are present by printing array content out with `print_r()` or even `var_dump()`. Then you either fix your typo or try to find why it is not here (if it really should be unconditionally). I'd also check your `<FORM>` and see if your `<input type="file"... />` element is really named and its name is "fileAudio".

Comment: Sorry, I included a comment in the code on where line 45 is and I included code where it contains the file input "fileAudio"

Comment: what `print_r($_FILES);` shows? Put it as first line in your upload handling code -> you can do `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES); die;` combo

Comment: When I do the `print_r($_FILES);` it outputs this after I upload a file: `Array ( [fileAudio] => Array ( [name] => lc2004-40k.mp3 [type] => audio/mp3 [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbRpBtm [error] => 0 [size] => 1210785 ) )`

Comment: Bit strange so now it is not a problem, let me just do some testing and I will get back to you, this is strange coz it wasn't working